# How to "Repeat" A Function In an Interval Periodically?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Given a function $f(x)$, how can you use sine (and not mod), to make $f(x)$ in an interval of $[a,b]$ to repeat every interval of $b-a$? In answers, use $f(x)=x$ as an example. I also do not expect it to be continuous.

Comment: In your example, what is the value of the new $f$ at $x=2b$ when $a=0$? Is it $f(a)$ or $f(b)$?

Comment: It should be $f(a)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about
$$f\left(\frac{a+b}2+\frac {b-a}\pi \arctan \left  ( \tan \left ( -\frac \pi 2 +\pi\frac {x-a} {b-a} \right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: This makes a triangular wave, not a sawtooth wave, which I think the OP wants.

Comment: We could fix it by multiplying the arcsin with $\mathrm{sign}(\cos(-\frac\pi2+\pi \frac{x-a}{b-a}))$. That may be in the vein of the OP's wishes? Except for the use of $\mathrm{sign}()$ maybe...

Comment: Actually, using $\arctan(\tan())$ instead of $\arcsin(\sin())$ makes a sawtooth.

Comment: Oops good point. I edited the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @StefanLafon Thank you! Answered the question perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

You want the period to be $b-a=T,$ so compose the function with a sinusoid with this period.